# react router dom v5 not rendering children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, rendering, react-router-dom

I tried a lot of tricks seen on the internet and on the official documentation of react router dom, like for example with or without "exact", other types of syntax but none of them allowed me to solve this mystery.

But, the question is why the second router does not display its components?

```
//index.js
ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider
        store={createStoreWithMiddleware(
          reducers,
          window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
          window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
        )}
      >
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Main router from app.js, work perfectly.

```
//app.js
      <Router>
        <TransitionGroup>
          <Switch location={location}>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <HomeView handleClick={handleClick} />} />
            [...]
            <Route path="/Profil" render={() => <ProfilView />} />
          </Switch>
        </TransitionGroup>
      </Router>
```

Profil page with a second router that not rendering components

```
            <Row>
                <Col xs={2} className='justify-content-center'>
                    <GroupBouton />
                </Col>
                <Col xs={10} className=''>
                    <Switch location={location}>
//when I go to this page I see the route below
                        <Route exact path={path} render={() => <h3>Choose a movie from the list above </h3>} />
//But this route is not rendering till I actualise the page by pushing F5
                        <Route path={`${path}/Myprofil`} render={() => <Myprofil />} />
                    </Switch>
                </Col>
            </Row>
```